# How do you draw what is in the image below on LaTeX

Tags: draw

[image]
I've tried multiple line drawing techniques but none of them seem to be producing the above, once they are drawn is it also possible to group them in a single row such that they can be moved altogether. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Do you like to have image as you show, or lines can be draw solid with help of some package as is `tikz` or `pstricks`, etc?. If you like to reproduce image as it ism, use `verbatim` environment. Please, show us, what you try so far.

Answer (score 11):

I always hoped this would become modern again one day. ;-)

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{verbatim}
              /\                                  /\
  /\         /  \/\               /\             /  \
 /  \     /\/      \             /  \       /\  /    \/\
/    \   /          \     /\/\/\/    \     /  \/        \/\
\end{verbatim}
\end{document}
```

[image]

It is rather straightforward to do that with Ti*k*Z (with my personal favorite proposal being the third one). Just dial some dash pattern.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[dash pattern=on 7.5pt off 3.5pt,shorten <=1.5pt,x=1ex,y=1em]
\draw[thick] (0,0) -- ++ (3,3) -- ++ (3,-3);
\draw[thick] (11,0) -- ++ (2,2) -- ++ (1,-1) -- ++ (3,3) -- ++ (2,-2)
 -- ++ (1,1) -- ++ (3,-3);
\draw[thick] (33,0) foreach \X in {1,2,3}{-- ++ (1,1) -- ++ (1,-1)} 
    -- ++ (3,3) -- ++ (3,-3); 
\draw[thick] (55,0) -- ++ (2,2) -- ++ (2,-2)
    -- ++ (4,4) -- ++ (3,-3) -- ++ (1,1) -- ++ (2,-2) -- ++ (1,1) -- ++ (1,-1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Or, since the choices are only up (`+`) and down (`-`), we can use the `parser` module.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepgfmodule{parser}
\pgfparserdef{pft}{initial}{the character -}% 
{\tikzset{insert path={-- ++(1,-1)}}}%
\pgfparserdef{pft}{initial}{the character +}% 
{\tikzset{insert path={-- ++(1,1)}}}%
\pgfparserdef{pft}{initial}{the character ;}% 
{\pgfparserswitch{final}}%
\tikzset{hillside/.code={\pgfparserparse{pft}#1;%
}}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[dash pattern=on 7.5pt off 3.5pt,shorten <=1.5pt,x=1ex,y=1em,
    thick]
\draw (0,0)[hillside={+++---}];
\draw (11,0)  [hillside={++-+++--+---}]; 
 -- ++ (1,1) -- ++ (3,-3);
\draw[thick] (33,0) [hillside={+-+-+-+++---}];  
\draw[thick] (55,0) [hillside={++--++++---+--+-}];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

You may also do away with the dash pattern, then.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepgfmodule{parser}
\pgfparserdef{pft}{initial}{the character -}% 
{\tikzset{insert path={edge[shorten <=1.75pt,shorten >=1.75pt] ++(1,-1) ++(1,-1)}}}%
\pgfparserdef{pft}{initial}{the character +}% 
{\tikzset{insert path={edge[shorten <=1.75pt,shorten >=1.75pt] ++(1,1) ++(1,1)}}}%
\pgfparserdef{pft}{initial}{the character ;}% 
{\pgfparserswitch{final}}%
\tikzset{hillside/.code={\pgfparserparse{pft}#1;%
}}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[x=1ex,y=1em,thick]
\draw (0,0)[hillside={+++---}];
\draw (11,0)  [hillside={++-+++--+---}]; 
\draw (33,0) [hillside={+-+-+-+++---}];  
\draw (55,0) [hillside={++--++++---+--+-}];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I would like to draw the lines and not use a picture, I've tried using coordinates with the \draw function but this is very tedious.

Comment: trees is the way to go

Comment: how would I go about doing this

Comment: +1 The `dash pattern` is amazing... fantastic... marvelous... perfect!

Comment: @PaulGaborit Merci! (I added a `parser` based variant.)

Comment: @Ali I added three Ti*k*Z variants. (My personal favorite is the last one.)

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat I really appreciate your help, will give it a go now!

Comment: @PaulGaborit legend

Comment: @PaulGaborit I'm totally agree with Paul Gaborit!!! Superbe the choose of the use of verbatim.