# How would I draw the following table in Latex?

Tags: tables, draw

This is the picture I'm trying to draw.

[image]

I've tried using the array function but end up with too many errors and this doesn't allow me to compile the code.

Comment: Please show what you tried so far. Please also add some clarification: What exactly is the problematic part?

Comment: @leandriis I've tried using the array function but keep getting errors so I've deleted the code.

Comment: You can start with a simple `tabular` environment. Do you have the contents of the second row available as images or did you try to use one of the methods prerented to you by Schrödinger's cat in the answers to one of your previous questions? (See: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/534003/134144) If so, which of the methods did you use?

Comment: @leandriis For the contents, I tried using one of the methods presented by Schrodinger's cat

Comment: Which one did you try using?

Comment: @leandriis I used this method \documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{verbatim}
              /\                                  /\
  /\         /  \/\               /\             /  \
 /  \     /\/      \             /  \       /\  /    \/\
/    \   /          \     /\/\/\/    \     /  \/        \/\
\end{verbatim}
\end{document}

Comment: Deleting code that does not really work but is not entire nonsense is something I never do. I usually have a `snippets.txt` file open where I keep my garbage for a while, or I cut and paste it below `\end{document}`.

Comment: Making the permutation get automatically generated will be much more interesting.

Answer (score 1):

Here are two simple examples. Probably you can use them as a starting point. For the image in the second column, I have used two different approaches that were given by Schrödinger's cat in the [answer to a previous question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/534003/134144):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|l|m{3cm}|l|}
\hline
$ n = 1$ &
\begin{verbatim}
  /\   
 /  \  
/    \ 
\end{verbatim}
& way\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
```

[image]

```
\end{document}


\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepgfmodule{parser}
\pgfparserdef{pft}{initial}{the character -}% 
{\tikzset{insert path={edge[shorten <=1.75pt,shorten >=1.75pt] ++(1,-1) ++(1,-1)}}}%
\pgfparserdef{pft}{initial}{the character +}% 
{\tikzset{insert path={edge[shorten <=1.75pt,shorten >=1.75pt] ++(1,1) ++(1,1)}}}%
\pgfparserdef{pft}{initial}{the character ;}% 
{\pgfparserswitch{final}}%
\tikzset{hillside/.code={\pgfparserparse{pft}#1;%
}}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|l|p{3cm}|l|}
\hline
$ n = 1$ &
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=1ex,y=1em,thick, baseline=(current bounding box.center)]
\draw (0,0)[hillside={+++---}];
\end{tikzpicture}
& ways
\\ \hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]